# How to deal with relative links from a subversion repository when branching and tagging?

Tags: svn, relative-path

We have a project which contains many subprojects, which contain relative links to files outside their trunk, to a parallel project containing shared code, for example:

```
shared/trunk/functions.sh
subproject1/trunk/main.sh
subproject2/trunk/main.sh
..
subproject99/trunk/main.sh
```

Where subproject*/trunk/main.sh invariably contains code like this:

```
# subprojectXX/trunk/main.sh
#!/bin/sh
source ../../shared/trunk/functions.sh
```

During the life of this project, we have made release tags for each of the subprojects, for example:

```
subproject1/tags/1.0.0
subproject1/tags/2.0.0
```

Now, I need to make a branch based on the 1.0.0 tag, but if I do

```
svn cp subproject1/tags/1.0.0 subproject1/branches/1.0.1
```

Then the relative paths to the shared functions no longer work.

I am tempted to do:

```
svn cp subproject1/tags/1.0.0 subproject1/trunk
```

Then do my work in trunk, and then copy it to a new tag when I'm done, eg:

```
svn cp subproject1/trunk subproject1/tags/1.0.1
```

However I am worried that this will cause all sorts of problems. Are my instincts correct?

Thanks for the suggestions about svn:externals, but I was looking for a solution that would be a little less intrusive to the (large) existing code base.

Thanks,

pix

Comment: Do you mean by parallel repo the same repo your current code is inside? Why don't you use svn:externals ?

Comment: What do you mean with “intrusive”? Externals were specifically designed to avoid the problem you're having. Instead of referring some outside folder, you'll be referring a folder inside the repo, there is no more difference, no more changes required.

Comment: By intrusive, I simply mean it will involve changing the 100+ subprojects. I guess most suggestions will involve this kind of change, but I'd like at least one alternate solution to compare against in terms of disruption.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).